# how to get guardian boundary in a-frame

Tags: aframe

I am working on a vr game that adapts the world to the players movement in their playspace.

To do so I need a list of the edges of the boundary of the gaurdian. How do you get that in a-frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bounded-floor is the property that that gives this
https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/webxr.html#properties2_bounded_floor

There is more info here in the webXR spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebXR_Device_API/Geometry

search that page for bounded-floor and it will take you to some more details, links and info.

Comment: Did you ever succeed in using this feature? `AFRAME.scenes[0].systems.webxr.sessionReferenceSpaceType` seems empty to me on quest, whether I have `local-floor` default or `bounded-floor` set.

Comment: No, I didn't pursue this much further as I was looking for a more programmatic vr dev framework. I am experimenting lua using [LÖVR](https://lovr.org) which does provide this as an array of points.

Comment: does it do that in web, or native?

Comment: Native. You use it to build an on device app.